# <c:catch> output value of the variable on the screen when no exception caught

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, tiles

In my web application I have to give this line to check whether an object has a field

```
<c:catch var="itemException">${item.masterOrderId}</c:catch>
```

However, it seems like when there is an exception thrown, the page works like desired, but when there currency item has a field `masterOrderId` then the page get a line of ugly output of all the master order id, like this

```
      7876288237088001859330060608701482416601260870751365393358087099973546544808785323837468560876664746049371087079881351783808767780494694690870295666366152083001
```

When i try to check the page source, interestingly I cannot find the string. so please let me know anything I can do to find out the trick, so I can do something to avoid of the nasty output.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the error occur if you don't use the catch block & target one item that you know has a masterOrderId? When you say "**the page get a line of ugly output of all the master order id**", do you mean that this 'ugly line' is all of the master IDs put together? Is this inside of a forEach loop that could be outputting them all on the same line?

Comment: @anotherdave thank you for the quick response. I should give more detail of context. I am creating a table tagx working for multiple places, however now the order table need specific parameters of each insertions master id. I cannot achieve it from jspx since the data model of the table is a list as `${orders}`, in the table tagx there is a `forEach` loop to go through the rows. So yes the line of ugly output of all the master order id is a concatenate of all the master order id of all orders. but that line is shown up outside the table, like a plain string.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the code for your <c:catch> statement, including the forEach loop? It's hard to get to the heart of it without seeing code, as it sounds like you've a reference to the masterId within the forEach loop but outside the table. The fact that you saw the string isn't in the HTML source is very strange however!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just looking again at your question:

*In my web application I have to give this line to check whether an object has a field*

```
<c:catch var="itemException">${item.masterOrderId}</c:catch>
```

If you have this as a line in your JSP, if the c:catch tag isn't getting an exception, it's executing the EL tag and printing out the ID to the page. Instead you should catch the ID at the point that it will be used. For example:

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="${item}" items="${items}">
    <c:catch var="itemException">
        <tr>
            <td>${item.a}</td>
            <td>${item.b}</td>
            <td>${item.masterOrderId}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:catch>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

That way if there is an exception the row gets surpressed, if not the ID gets outputted in an appropriate place.